# If X and Y are independent and both uniform on [0,1], what is the probability density function of Z=Y/X

Tags: probability, statistics

Since X and Y are independent and uniform I have the joint density function f(x,y)=1 but Im not sure where to go from there.  I keep getting that the answer is f(z)=1 but this doesnt make sense since the range of z is from 0 to infinity.

So if I make the substitution Z=Y/X and W=X, I get Y=ZW and X=W.  The 4 derivatives for the Jacobian are $\frac{dx}{dz}=0$, $\frac{dx}{dw}=1$, $\frac{dy}{dz}=W$ and $\frac{dy}{dw}=Z$  which give |J|=W and so f(z,w)=$1*w$

The range of W is 0,1 which and integrating W over that range just gives f(z)=1.  This answer doesnt make sense to me since the range of Z is 0 to $\infty$ and f(z) should integrate to 1 over that range.  I think I am making a mistake somewhere right after I get f(z,w)=w but Im not sure where.

Comment: Use the jacobian method. Please add your work in your post if you want help

Comment: updated, Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So if I make the substitution Z=Y/X and W=X, I get Y=ZW and X=W.

I'd just do $Y=ZX$ and $X=X$, with no need to introduce a new variable which is just $X$ renamed, but yes, the Jacobian's absolute determinant is $\lvert X\rvert$.

So what is the support?  Well $f_{X,Y}(x,zx) = \mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant zx\leqslant 1}$, so we will be integrating over $0\leqslant x\lt \min\{1,1/z\}$ for any $0\lt z$.  We should thus partition the domain for $z$ into $0<z<1$ and $1\leqslant z$

$$\begin{align}f_Z(z)&=\int_\Bbb R f_{X,Z}(x,z)\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_\Bbb R\left\lvert\dfrac{\partial zx}{\partial z}
\right\rvert f_{X,Y}(x,zx)\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_\Bbb R\lvert x\rvert\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant zx\leqslant 1}\,\mathrm d x\\&=\mathbf 1_{0<z<1}\int_0^1x\mathrm d x+\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant z}\int_0^{1/z}x\mathrm d x\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Comment: OOOOKK thats what I was missing.  I thought I might be missing some sort of partition or something but I couldnt figure out what it might be.  Thank you very much.

Comment: So our final solution would be $\frac {1}{2}$ for $0<z<1$ and $\frac {1}{2z^2}$ for z>1   I dont see how we can add them together because the final f(z) should integrate to 1 over 0 to infinity

Comment: Yes.  Remember the indicator functions equal $0$ when $z$ is outside their support. $$\begin{align}f_{Z}(z) &= \tfrac 12\mathbf 1_{0<z<1}+\tfrac 1{2z^2}\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant z}\\&=\begin{cases}0&:&z\leqslant 0\\ 1/2&:&0<z<1\\1/(2z^2)&:&1<z\end{cases}\\[2ex]\therefore\qquad\int_\Bbb R f_Z(z)\mathrm d z &=\int_0^1 \tfrac 12\mathrm d z+\int_1^\infty \tfrac1{2z^2}\,\mathrm d z\\&=\tfrac 12+\tfrac 12\end{align}$$

Comment: Thats excellent.  Thank you very much I was really struggling with the whole "partitions" thing but this was a good example to help drive it home

Comment: @Bill if this answer helps you, you should accept it by clicking the grey tick-mark on the left. For details, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287

Comment: @Henry. Good idea on the graphics hint. But now that we have this nice answer, I think I'll de-clutter this page by deleting that item. Especially since OP has already seen the graphs.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to comment.  So I have to put this hint down as an "answer".  Sorry.

You are on the right track, Bill.  Your just missed one thing. Think carefully about the domain for the joint PDF $f_{W,Z}(w,z)$.

Comment: I figured this was likely where I was making my mistake but for the life of me I cant figure out what range of W makes this work.  The PDF f(w,z)=1 is correct though right?